# How to stop a Tkinter PhotoImage being cropped in Python

Tags: python, tkinter, label, crop

I wish to load images on a list click event, from a URL and then display them within a Tkinter Label. When I load them they display cropped. Can someone tell me why please?

```
def OnSelect(evt):
    w = evt.widget
    index = int(w.curselection()[0])
    print("URL : " + URLs[index])
    response = requests.get(URLs[index])
    img_data = response.content
    image = Image.open(BytesIO(img_data))
    img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
    panelImage.configure(image=img, width=50, height=10)
    panelImage.image = img
```

```
panelImage = Tkinter.Label(window, text="", width=50, height=10, borderwidth=4, relief="ridge")
panelImage.grid(column=2, row=1)
```

Thanks

Comment: You're specifically setting the width and height of the label that contains the image. have you tried removing the hard-coded size?

Comment: Bryan Oakley - fantastic thank you! A bit of a "doh!" moment. :-)

Answer (score 0):

As Byan Oakley very correctly said...

```
panelImage.configure(image=img)
```

and

```
panelImage = Tkinter.Label(window, text="", borderwidth=4, relief="ridge")
```